# Flutter Chewie Video Player - check when playback is complete

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the Chewie Video player in my Flutter app. How to check when playback has completed, so that I can close the screen and dispose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can check `position` and `duration` 
full code is official example set loop to `false` and add the following code snippet

code snippet

```
_videoPlayerController1.addListener(() {
      if (_videoPlayerController1.value.position ==
          _videoPlayerController1.value.duration) {
        print('video Ended');
      }
    });
```

Output

```
I/flutter ( 4881): video Ended
```

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:chewie/src/chewie_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChewieDemo(),
  );
}

class ChewieDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  ChewieDemo({this.title = 'Chewie Demo'});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChewieDemoState();
  }
}

class _ChewieDemoState extends State<ChewieDemo> {
  TargetPlatform _platform;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController1;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController2;
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');
    _videoPlayerController2 = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/asdasdas.mp4');
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: false,
      // Try playing around with some of these other options:

      // showControls: false,
      // materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
      //   playedColor: Colors.red,
      //   handleColor: Colors.blue,
      //   backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      //   bufferedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      // ),
      // placeholder: Container(
      //   color: Colors.grey,
      // ),
      // autoInitialize: true,
    );

    _videoPlayerController1.addListener(() {
      if (_videoPlayerController1.value.position ==
          _videoPlayerController1.value.duration) {
        print('video Ended');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController1.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController2.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: widget.title,
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        platform: _platform ?? Theme.of(context).platform,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _chewieController.enterFullScreen();
              },
              child: Text('Fullscreen'),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _chewieController.dispose();
                        _videoPlayerController2.pause();
                        _videoPlayerController2.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));
                        _chewieController = ChewieController(
                          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
                          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          looping: true,
                        );
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Video 1"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _chewieController.dispose();
                        _videoPlayerController1.pause();
                        _videoPlayerController1.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));
                        _chewieController = ChewieController(
                          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController2,
                          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          looping: true,
                        );
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: Text("Error Video"),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _platform = TargetPlatform.android;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Android controls"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _platform = TargetPlatform.iOS;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: Text("iOS controls"),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer above is correct, but this 'video ended' is called immediately i start playing, i had to wrap with this if statement, before it works well for me

```
  videoController.addListener(() {
  if (videoController.value.position.inSeconds > 0) {
    if (videoController.value.position == videoController.value.duration) {
      print('video Ended');
      isFinished.value = true;
    }
  }
});
```